# JPA saving primary and foreign key together

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two Entities `DealEntity` and `DealTypeEntity`
and they are related as-

```
@Entity
class DealEntity{
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "DEAL_TYPE_ID")
  private DealTypeEntity dealTypeEntity;
}
```

I am trying to save by creating instance of DealEntity which contains DealTypeEntity ref.

I am using JPA and it giving me exception in `entityManager.persist(entity)`

```
     Oct 17, 2013 3:36:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
     SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path             [/Travel-Portal] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is          org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:org.hibernate.TransientPropertyV alueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient  instance before flushing: training.impetus.tp.model.DealEntity.dealTypeEntity ->  training.impetus.tp.model.DealTypeEntity; nested exception is  java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object  references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:  training.impetus.tp.model.DealEntity.dealTypeEntity ->  training.impetus.tp.model.DealTypeEntity] with root cause
 org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient i nstance - save the transient instance before flushing:  training.impetus.tp.model.DealEntity.dealTypeEntity ->  training.impetus.tp.model.DealTypeEntity
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$8.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:176)
    at o rg.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEv entListener.java:160)
    at o  rg.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlus hingEventListener.java:151)
    at o    rg.hiborg.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hib
```

Comment: Look at setting the cascade mode on @ManyToOne(cascade = ...). If DealTypeEntity is new (transient) rather than an existing persistent entity then you need to tell Hibernate to save this as well - which various cascade options will do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Either you do what the error message propose "save the transient instance before flushing"

```
entityManager.persist(dealTypeEntity);
entityManager.persist(dealEntity);
```

or you could change the annotation in DealEntity to

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
// then persisting DealEntity would persist the childs also
entityManager.persist(dealEntity);
```

Comment: "you do what the error message propose"... so obvious that I didn't figure out how simple it was... Thanks for this neat answer on the annotation. Saved my day !

Answer (score 0):

There is another scenario where we can get the same error,
We had this same issue when we manually inserted an entry with update_count column as null value.  So we had a member table that relates to fund table. We inserted a new fund manually and forgot to put a value for update_count.  When the application created a member with this fund we got this exception while saving the member data `org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:` . We are using update_count column for version control [@version].

Answer (score 0):

instead of passing reference object passed the saved object, below is explanation which solve my issue,

//wrong

entityManager.persist(dealTypeEntity);

dealEntity.setDealType(dealTypeEntity);

entityManager.persist(dealEntity)

//right

DealTypeEntity savedEntity= entityManager.persist(dealTypeEntity);

dealEntity.setDealType(savedEntity);

entityManager.persist(dealEntity)